# Display android ringer volume

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an app that simply displays the volume value on the screen.  Below is the code that I have written and I feel as though it should work but when I run it, I get a value of 7 but never changes no matter how many time I change the volume of my ringer.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int myCurrentVolume = 0;
    String myString = "Hello World";
    AudioManager myAudio;


    private TextView myVolumeLevel;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myVolumeLevel = (TextView) this
                .findViewById(R.id.text_VolumeLevel);

        myAudio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        myCurrentVolume = myAudio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME);


        String myString = String.valueOf(myCurrentVolume);
        myVolumeLevel.setText(myString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the ringer volume, you need to change the call to `getStreamVolume()` to this:

```
myCurrentVolume = myAudio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```